# Probability distribution of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Their sum is $Z = X + Y$. How can I calculate the conditional distribution of $P(Z|X)$?

Comment: Do you mean the conditional distribution? or the conditional expectation?

Comment: @Ju'x: I mean the conditional distribution. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the conditional distribution of $Z$ conditioned by $X$ is defined as any family of probability measures $(\mu_x)_x$ such that, for every bounded function $u$, one has $E[u(Z)\mid X]=v(X)$, where the function $v$ is defined as
$$
v(x)=\int u(z)\mathrm d\mu_x(z).
$$
Here, one can take for each $\mu_x$ the distribution of $x+Y$. Thus, introducing the distribution $\nu$ of $Y$, for every Borel subset $B$ and every $x$, one sets
$$
\mu_x(B)=P[x+Y\in B]=\nu(B-x).
$$